# Advantage of named pipes over anonymous pipes c++

Tags: c++, mfc, pipe

What are the advantages of using a named pipe over an anonymous pipe. How a named pipe can be used to communicate to a remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Named pipes allow the client software to open the pipe without actually being a process that is started from the process that owns the pipe.

With a named pipe you can also connect from one machine to another (via some system level software that connects the machines together, of course). Since unnamed pipes can't be "found" from another machine, you couldn't use unnamed pipes for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example of using named pipes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx